# Bitnami Helm WordPress secretes issue

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to use my own existing kubernetes secrets for the 'WORDPRESS_PASSWORD' variable. And it should not create SVC from wordpress helm.
For this I used below code in the values.yaml file But changes are not reflecting.

```
wordpress:
  wordpressUsername: admin
  wordpressPassword: foo
  extraEnvVarsSecret:
    - name: WORDPRESS_PASSWORD
      value: application-secret
```

Please suggest me for the same.